Beam RunInference and sentence-transformers from huggingface
I am trying to use RunInference beam Transform, together with stsb-xlm-r-multilingual model.
Like so:
  inferences = (
            formatted_examples
            | "Run Inference" >> RunInference(model_handler)
            | 'ProcessOutput' >> beam.ParDo(PostProcessor())
  )

While model_handler is:
model_handler = HuggingFacePipelineModelHandler(
    task=PipelineTask.FeatureExtraction,
    model = "sentence-transformers/stsb-xlm-r-multilingual",
    load_pipeline_args={'framework': 'pt'},
    inference_args={'max_length': 200}
)

However, the predictionResult object that is returned by the transform, contains an a nested array, with multiple embeddings.
I can access the embedding like so:
result.inference[0][0][0].
That provides me with a single embedding.
I am not sure what are all the other embeddings. I am interested in just one, I don't need all the data.
While I can always get the embedding by using inner indices like I showed above, I am wondering whether I am doing something wrong, or is there a way to pass some parameters to the handler, to instruct it to return only a single embedding?
Thank you
